# What to put for `p` in a binomial test to obtain a CI?

Tags: r, confidence-interval, binomial-distribution

I have a simple binomial test in which $55$ successes out of $100$ trials have been found. In `R`, it is necessary to pick a `p` (probability of success) to run a binomial test and obtain a $Confidence ~Interval$.

In my case, I was wondering if I should put $.55$ ($55$ out of $100$) for that `p`?

```
binom.test(55, 100, p = .55)$conf.int
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put in anything you want. `binom.test` 's `p` parameter is the null value of $p$ for a null hypothesis for a hypothesis test. If you only want the confidence interval, this number is immaterial. Check for yourself: change the value and notice how nothing happens to the `conf.int` member.

Comment: So, by "`binom.test` 's `p` parameter is the null value of `p` for a null hypothesis for a hypothesis test" you mean by default `p` is considered `.5`?

Comment: @Reza yes, check out the help page by typing `?binom.test`. The default null hypothesis is that p = 0.5:

`binom.test(x, n, p = 0.5,
           alternative = c("two.sided", "less", "greater"),
           conf.level = 0.95)`

Comment: @Reza that number is for a hypothesis test, and has no bearing on your confidence interval. The default value for this is $.5$, but I did not mention that in my answer.

Comment: There are different methods to calculate a confidence interval for a binomial proportion.  In R, in the [DescTools](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/DescTools/versions/0.99.19) package, there's a function `BinomCI` that has options for several methods.   Also, there's a function in DescTools, `MultinomCI`, that produces confidence intervals for multinominal proportions.  A few examples of these function are [here](http://rcompanion.org/handbook/H_02.html).